# How do I run a command line tool in a Rails app on a docker container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

so I have a working Rails project which is running in a docker container

I have a need to use this tool : https://github.com/google/oauth2l

I need to use this tool within my rails application, take it's output and use it in a post request I'm making via HTTParty.

I'm able to do this already but that's assuming I have oauth2l installed on my system. But since

I'm running my app in production in a container, I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is.

In the docs, there does seem to be a way to 'inject' it into my container but adding those lines to the Dockerfile is leading to syntax errors.

Any ideas on what I could do here?

Comment: Can you show us your Dockerfile? What syntax errors is it causing? You have to add `oauth2l` to your container image to get it to work. There's no way around it

Comment: Normally you `bundle install` as part of making the container.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, `I think you shouldn't run commands inside the docker container unless you really need it`, the best approach is to install what you need while you are `building your docker image` (with only `docker` or `docker-compose`), but in case you really need to `enter` inside your `container` here is how I usually do it:

```
sudo -s
docker container ls (list all containers)

docker container -ti <id of the container> sh
or
docker exec -ti <id of the container> /bin/bash
```

The `sudo -s` sometimes is needed depending on how you configure the instance where your container is running, which means that all the commands you are running from now on are like admin. And you may need to execute `sh` or `bash`, again depending on your instance.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Is better to type all the commands needed in the Dockerfile.
BUt, if you want to run a command within the container, try this:

`docker exec -it my-app-web-1 rails db:create db:migrate`
`docker exec -it my-app-web-1 rails devise:install`

These are some examples that you can do.